# Debug Test in Dotnet xUnit does not break at Breakpoint

Tags: visual-studio-code, xunit

I am using dotnet core, VS Code and xUnit for tests.

I can run the test, but when I try to debug the test, it does not break at the breakpoint?

[image]

What do I need to do, to get it to break at the breakpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the problem. I am using cross platform .NET Core debugger, which does not support Windows PDB.

This is easily fixed by changing project.json to include "debugType":"portable"

```
"buildOptions": {
  "emitEntryPoint": true,
  "preserveCompilationContext": true,
  "debugType": "portable"
},
```